# btproxy fails to bind to Bluetooth socket while trying to proxy Bluetooth device to QEMU

Tags: qemu, bluez

I am following the guide for Zephyr to run on QEMU using the host system Bluetooth controller. I am on Ubuntu 20.10 which is lacking btproxy, so I built BlueZ as described in the guide linked below. I have also enabled the experimental mode for `bluetoothd`

Starting btproxy works fine, but when I start Zephyr on QEMU I get the following error.

```
sudo tools/btproxy -u -i 0
Opening user channel for hci0
Failed to bind Bluetooth socket: Device or resource busy
```

I thought maybe the Ubuntu shell was keeping the Bluetooth controller occupied and maybe it is. Switching it off in the settings just rfkills it preventing btproxy from working. I have also enabled

Trying to run Zephyr in Native POSIX mode fails as well, it is unable to open the driver.

```
sax@decibel:~/zephyrproject/zephyr$ sudo ./build/zephyr/zephyr.exe --bt-dev=hci0
*** Booting Zephyr OS build zephyr-v2.5.0-530-gff5b040f7822  ***
Starting Beacon Demo
[00:00:00.000,000] <err> bt_hci_core: HCI driver open failed (-16)
Bluetooth init failed (err -16)
```

I have tried the above with both an Asus USB-BT400 and an Asus USB-BT500 with similar results. Is there anything I may have forgotten? Could it be due to a BlueZ version mismatch between what I built and what is shipped with Ubuntu 20.10?

https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/guides/bluetooth/bluetooth-tools.html#bluetooth-qemu-posix

Comment: Someone else seems to have had the same problem, but no solution was mentioned. I'm not sure if it is related, but it seems Bluetooth support has been removed from QEMU. https://www.mail-archive.com/qemu-devel@nongnu.org/msg697630.html

Comment: I am stuck in the same situation did you manged that ? if yes how ?